# Django: Create a ManyToMany() relationship to store multivalues

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the `Diagnosis` table in `models.py`. The `diagnosis_option` can store multiple values (maybe more than one) from `diagnosis_option_value` field.

Here is my `Diagnosis` table.

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):

    age_of_diagnosis = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    age_at_onset_of_symptoms = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    diagnosis_option_value = (
        ('', 'Please select a diagnosis'),
        ('b-thalassaemia syndromes', 'b-thalassaemia syndromes'),
        ('a-thalassaemia syndromes', 'a-thalassaemia syndromes'),
        ('Sickle cell syndromes', 'Sickle cell syndromes'),
        ('Other haemoglobin variants','Other haemoglobin variants'),
        ('Rare cell membrane disorders','Rare cell membrane disorders'),
        ('Rare cell enzyme disorders','Rare cell enzyme disorders'),
        ('Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias','Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias')
    )
    diagnosis_option = models.CharField( max_length=30)
    record_of_genotype = models.CharField(max_length=45,null=True,blank=True)
    # icd_10_code = models.ForeignKey(icd_10)
    icd_10_code = models.CharField('ICD-10 code', max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    # icd_10_desc = models.CharField('ICD-10 description',max_length=80,null=True,blank=True)
    icd_10_desc = models.ForeignKey(icd_10)
    orpha_code = models.CharField('Oprha code', max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    #diagnosis_genotype = models.CharField('Diagnosis genotype', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    diagnosis_circumstances = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    diagnosis_circumstances_date = models.DateField('Date of diagnosis',null=True,blank=True)
    date_of_input= models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Demographic)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient)
```

In order to save multiple values it was suggested to create another table to have `ManytoMany` relationship.

I created `DiagnosisOption` like below:

```
class DiagnosisOption(models.Model):
    diag_option_value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    diag_option = models.ManyToManyField(Diagnosis)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.diag_option
```

How does `diag_option` will get values from `diagnosis_option`?

In `forms.py` my code is the one below. For `diagnosis_option` I use `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()` widget.

```
class DiagnosisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(DiagnosisForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['diagnosis_circumstances_date']= forms.DateField(label=('Date'),required=False,
        widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
                                       "pickTime": False,
                                       "startDate": "1900-01-01"}))

        self.helper=FormHelper(form=self)

        self.fields['icd_10_desc']= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=icd_10.objects.all(),
                                    widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget("icd_10Autocomplete"))
        self.fields['icd_10_desc'].label = "ICD-10 description"
        diagnosis_option_value = (
        ('b-thalassaemia syndromes', 'b-thalassaemia syndromes',),
        ('a-thalassaemia syndromes', 'a-thalassaemia syndromes'),
        ('Sickle cell syndromes', 'Sickle cell syndromes'),
        ('Other haemoglobin variants','Other haemoglobin variants'),
        ('Red cell membrane disorders','Red cell membrane disorders'),
        ('Red cell enzyme disorders','Red cell enzyme disorders'),
        ('Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias','Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias')
    )
        self.fields['diagnosis_option']=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=diagnosis_option_value, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())


        diagnosis_circumstances_value = (
        ('Antenatal diagnosis','Antenatal diagnosis'),
        ('Neonatal diagnosis','Neonatal diagnosis'),
        ('By the presence of affected related','By the presence of affected related'),
        ('Clinical diagnosis', 'Clinical diagnosis'),
        ('Other','Other')

        )
        self.fields['diagnosis_circumstances']=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=diagnosis_circumstances_value, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
        #self.fields['patient'].queryset = Demographic.objects.filter(patient_id=self.instance.patient)
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3'

        #self.helper.form_class = 'forms-horizontal'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset (
                # 'patient',
                '<b>Diagnosis information</b>',
                Div(
                    #HTML(u'<div class="col-md-2"></div>'),
                    Div('age_of_diagnosis',css_class='col-md-6'),
                    Div('age_at_onset_of_symptoms',css_class="col-md-6"),
                    css_class='row',
                    ),



                'diagnosis_option',
                'record_of_genotype',
                'icd_10_desc',
                'icd_10_code',
                'orpha_code',
                'comment',
                ),

            Fieldset(
                '<b>Diagnosis circumstances</b>',
                'diagnosis_circumstances',
                'diagnosis_circumstances_date',
                #'diagnosis_circumstances_caring_year',
                ),



            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = Diagnosis
        exclude = ['patient', 'author']

        list_display = ('patient', 'pub_date', 'author')
        # autocomplete_js_attribute={'name': 'icd_10_code'}
```

THIS IS MY SOLUTION regarding AKS proposed solution:

`models.py`

```
class DiagnosisOption(models.Model):
    diagnosis_option_value = (
        ('', 'Please select a diagnosis'),
        ('b-thalassaemia syndromes', 'b-thalassaemia syndromes'),
        ('a-thalassaemia syndromes', 'a-thalassaemia syndromes'),
        ('Sickle cell syndromes', 'Sickle cell syndromes'),
        ('Other haemoglobin variants','Other haemoglobin variants'),
        ('Rare cell membrane disorders','Rare cell membrane disorders'),
        ('Rare cell enzyme disorders','Rare cell enzyme disorders'),
        ('Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias','Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias')
    )

    diag_option = models.CharField( max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.diag_option

class Diagnosis(models.Model):

    ...
    diagnosis_option = models.ManyToManyField(DiagnosisOption)
```

`forms.py`:
In `DiagnosisForm`:

```
diagnosis_option_value = (
        ('b-thalassaemia syndromes', 'b-thalassaemia syndromes',),
        ('a-thalassaemia syndromes', 'a-thalassaemia syndromes'),
        ('Sickle cell syndromes', 'Sickle cell syndromes'),
        ('Other haemoglobin variants','Other haemoglobin variants'),
        ('Red cell membrane disorders','Red cell membrane disorders'),
        ('Red cell enzyme disorders','Red cell enzyme disorders'),
        ('Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias','Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias')
    )
        self.fields['diagnosis_option']=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=DiagnosisOption.objects.all().values_list('id','diag_option'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

`views.py`:

In `request.method=POST`:

```
my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(request.POST, prefix='diag')

for formfield in my_diagnosis:
                dia_id = formfield.name
                if formfield.name == 'diagnosis_option':
                    dig_opt_list =  formfield.value()

my_diagnosis_object = my_diagnosis.save(commit=False)
            my_diagnosis_object.author = request.user
            my_diagnosis_object.patient = my_demographics_object
            my_diagnosis_object.save()

            for x in xrange(0, len(dig_opt_list)):
                my_diagnosis_object.diagnosis_option.add(dig_opt_list[x])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it in following way:

Move the choices to `DiagnosisOption` class:

```
class DiagnosisOption(models.Model):
    diagnosis_option_value = (
        ('', 'Please select a diagnosis'),
        ('b-thalassaemia syndromes', 'b-thalassaemia syndromes'),
        ('a-thalassaemia syndromes', 'a-thalassaemia syndromes'),
        ('Sickle cell syndromes', 'Sickle cell syndromes'),
        ('Other haemoglobin variants','Other haemoglobin variants'),
        ('Rare cell membrane disorders','Rare cell membrane disorders'),
        ('Rare cell enzyme disorders','Rare cell enzyme disorders'),
        ('Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias','Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias')
    )

    diag_option = models.CharField( max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.diag_option
```

And, add it as a `ManyToManyField` in `Diagnosis` class:

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):

    # other fields

    diagnosis_options = models.ManyToManyField(DiagnosisOption)
```

Comment: I don't think this wants to be a many-to-many at all. Since you're providing the options as a choice in DiagnosisOption, you just need a ForeignKey from there back to Diagnosis. Each combination of (diag_option, diagnosis) is unique, so no need for M2M.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: The OP wants to have multiple diagnosis options saved for a diagnosis.

Comment: Yes; a ForeignKey from DiagnosisOption to Diagnosis would achieve that. What they don't need is multiple Diagnoses for each DiagnosisOption.

Comment: Well, that is not clear from the question itself. It seems only OP can clear this query.. Can there be multiple diagnoses related to one DiagnosisOption?

Comment: Dear all, for each `Diagnosis` I can have one or many values from `DiagnosisOption`.

Comment: @zinon: Please check the question in my last comment. Is vice versa is also True? Can there be multiple `Diagnosis` related to one `DiagnosisOption`?

Comment: @AKS Yes, Actually I have 7 Diagnosis options and `Diagnosis` can have one or more. On the other hand, one `DiagnosisOption` can be related to none, one or many `Diagnosis`.

Comment: @zinon: In that case, you can use the `ManyToManyField` as in my answer.

Comment: @AKS In that case how to I save the selected values?

Comment: @AKS I have ` my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(request.POST, prefix='diag')` to handle `Diagnosis` fields and I save them using `my_diagnosis_object = my_diagnosis.save(commit=False)` and next `my_diagnosis_object.save()` but the selected values are not stored. In case I go to `localhost/admin` I can update and save multivalues. What can I do in `views.py`?

Comment: @AKS Thank you! I found the solution! I updated my question including my solution regarding your proposed solution! Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove diagnosis_option from Diagnosis.
Then you have DianosisOption as a separate model.
When you create a ManyToMany you can access in both directions. Here in the following example I gave the name `diagnosis_options` to the Diagosis -> DiagnosisOption relation so you'll be able to get all the options by doing:

```
yourDiagnosisInstace.diagnosisOptions.all()
```

Hope it helps sorry if there is a syntax error, I didn't have time to test it.

```
class DiagnosisOption(models.Model):
diagnosis_option_value = (
    ('', 'Please select a diagnosis'),
    ('b-thalassaemia syndromes', 'b-thalassaemia syndromes'),
    ('a-thalassaemia syndromes', 'a-thalassaemia syndromes'),
    ('Sickle cell syndromes', 'Sickle cell syndromes'),
    ('Other haemoglobin variants','Other haemoglobin variants'),
    ('Rare cell membrane disorders','Rare cell membrane disorders'),
    ('Rare cell enzyme disorders','Rare cell enzyme disorders'),
    ('Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias','Congenital dyserythropoietic anaemias')
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=diagnosis_option_value)
diag_option = models.ManyToManyField(Diagnosis,  related_name="diagnosis_options")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to I save to `DiagnosisOption`? In my `forms.py` I have `self.fields['DiagnosisOption__name']=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=diagnosis_option_value, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())`.

Comment: It should be something like:
`your_diagnosis.diagnosis_options.add(your_diagnosis_option)`

I recommend to remove the choices (diagnosis_option_value ) and create and admin view to manage your options from there. Then in your form to set the choices just do something like `choiches=DiagnosisOption.objects.all()`

Let me know!